# Number of functions $f:\{1, 2, \ldots, n\} \to \{0, 1\}$ that assign $1$ to exactly one positive integer less than $n$

Tags: combinatorics

**I've seen this question is discrete maths text :

> How many functions are there from the set $\{1, 2, . . . , n\},$ where $n$
>   is a positive integer, to the set $\{0, 1\}.$
>
> a) that assign to $1$ exactly one of the positive integers less than $n$?

The answer for this question is $2(n-1).$

Shouldn't the answer be $2^{n-1}?$

My Idea for that answer : There will be total of $2^n$ functions. And the condition says that it has to assign '1' to integers less than 'n' which means there will be $(n-1)$ possibilities.

So the answer should be $2^{n-1}$ functions ..Right? Explain please.

Comment: How many ways are there to pick the single element less than $n$ that gets the value $1$? Once you've done that, how many ways are there to finish the function?

Answer (score 7):

The functions to be counted are those that assign to $1$ exactly one (one and only one) of the integers less than $n$ (*one* of the elements in $\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$. Once that assignment is determined $(n-1$ choice $)$, the remaining elements in $\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ must then be assigned to $0$.

Then $n$ itself can be assigned to $0$ or $1$.

So there are two choices for assigning $n$, and $n-1$ choices to assign to $1$.

That gives $2(n-1)$ possible functions that satisfy the given requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much Jordan. Can you please explain why we can not say, there are $(n-1)$ choices to assign to 1 and there are $(n-1)$ choices to assign them to 0 and finally 2 for $n$, so we have $(n-1) + (n-1)  + 2$.

Answer (score -1):

Let set $A = \{1,2,3...n\}$ and $B = {0,1}$
Therefore, set $A$ needs to map with set $B$

For without any restriction to mapping, each element of set $A$ can mapped with element $0$ or element $1$ of the set $B$, therefore the ways without restriction is: $2$ to power $n$ or $2^n$.

For the given condition that 1 element of set $A$ will have element $1$ of set $B$ for sure. Therefore, the answer as per the condition: $nC1 \cdot 2^n-1$.

Where:

1. $nC1$: stands for the selection of that element of set $A$ that will store element 1
2. $2^n-1$: stands for the remaining elements that can have either $0$ or $1$