# counting: How many functions are there from the set $ \{1,2,...,n\} $where $n$ is a positive integer, to the set $\{0,1\}$ what does he mean?

Tags: combinatorics

I didn't get the question, does he mean any function that its domain is subset of the first set and the codomain is subset of the other?
for example for $n=2$
$$f : \phi \rightarrow \phi$$
$$f : \{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$$
$$f : \{1, 2\} \rightarrow \{1\}$$
and so on?

Comment: No, the domain has to be the whole of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$.  There is no reference to a subset.  If $n=1$, the answer is $2$:  the two functions are $f(1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264529/number-of-functions-f-1-2-ldots-n-to-0-1-that-assign-1-to-exac  Related?

Comment: One example of a function from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ is $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=1\\1&\text{if }x=2\\0&\text{if }x=3\\0&\text{if }x=4\end{cases}$ and another might be $g(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=1\\1&\text{if }x=2\\1&\text{if }x=3\\1&\text{if }x=4\end{cases}$.  For convenience sake, let us shorthand those as $0100$ and $1111$ respectively.  Do you see the similarity?  Have you seen anything about counting the number of binary sequences of length $n$?

Comment: I got it thank you!

Comment: He means how many subsets of $\{1\ldots n\}$. Every such $f$ determines a subset.

Comment: @eigengrau Personally, I wouldn't phrase it that way specifically as it does not translate well to the question of how many functions there are from $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ to $\{0,1,2\}$.  That analogy only works for where the codomain is $\{0,1\}$.  It is more useful in my opinion to be comfortable with the current phrasing and the objects involved in the current phrasing.  That said, I do agree that being able to spot such rewordings and bijections to other scenarios is important and that is indeed a good one to notice.

Comment: @JMoravitz Then (for $\to\{0,1,2\}$)  it's just how many partitions. I think that's the most intuitive way to think about it, especially in the op's $\to\{0,1\}$ specific case. For the more general partition case, I probably wouldn't have bothered commenting. I only remarked about the generalization due to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punchline at the end of the day is that the set of functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is often given the convenient notation of $B^A$.  It is a convenient notation because we then have the result:

$$|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$$

This is proven for example by the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorics%2C%20the%20rule%20of,ways%20of%20performing%20both%20actions.).  For the first element of $A$ pick which element of $B$ it gets mapped to.  Then for the second element of $A$ again pick which element of $B$ it gets mapped to, repeating the process until having chosen where each element of $A$ gets mapped and combining the results together via multiplication.

Here, $$|\{0,1\}^{\{1,2,\dots,n\}}| = |\{0,1\}|^{|\{1,2,\dots,n\}|} = 2^n$$